# How can I grant access to only one app in a Firebase Project?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform

I have two apps in a Firebase project (Android and iOS). I want to give access to my developer-only iOS app. How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase controls access at the *project* level, not at the app level.  All of the permissions you grant to someone in a project apply across everything in that project.  That includes all apps that you might have added to the project.  The apps are not sandboxed from each other - they share all resources in the project where they were added.

It sounds like you want to create two apps in two different projects, and give access to only one of those projects.  It is common to sandbox developer access this way.

See also:

- https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/iam/overview
- https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7000272?hl=en